# edit mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am missing something and I need some help!

The below code generates a table with editable fields. When I edit the fields it passes that data to my edit page which will run an UPDATE script. But when I hit the Update button on any row it sends every record in the while loop. How do I limit that to just the record I have selected to update?

Thanks for your help!

```
$sitequery = "SELECT * FROM meterdata WHERE address LIKE '%$site%' ORDER BY apart_num + 0";

$siteresult = mysqli_query($connection,$sitequery);
    echo "<form action='editmeter.php' method='get'>";
$resultstring = '<table class="table table-hover">';
$resultstring .= '<tr>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Apartment</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Address</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Suburb</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Meter</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Meter Loction</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Type</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Units</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Start Read</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Read Date</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Waveflow</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Status</th>';
$resultstring .= '<th>Notes</th>';
$resultstring .= '</tr>';

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($siteresult)){

    $resultstring .= "<tr>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='text' value='$data[apart_num]' name='apart' name='apart' </td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[address]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[suburb]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='text' value='$data[meter_serial]' name='serial' ></td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[meter_location]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='text' value='$data[meter_type]' name='type'></td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='text' value='$data[meter_units]' name='unit'></td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='text' value='$data[start_read]' name='read'></td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[start_read_date]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[node_address]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[status]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td>$data[notes]</td>";
    $resultstring .= "<td><input type='submit' value='Update'></td>";
    echo"</from>";
    $resultstring .= "</tr>";

    }



$resultstring .= '</table>';


echo $resultstring;
```

Comment: are you updating the correct row? does that particular row correspond to the correct id you want to be updated?

Comment: we need the actual update code (with the update query) to help you.

Comment: The UPDATE is not the problem, when I hit Update I should be sending apart,serial,type,unit and read of the one I have selected to edit meter.php. What I get is only the last record in the query not the one I select update for. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also the + 0 is just a nice way of getting varchar numbers to display correctly

Comment: If the whole table is one form, all of the fields on that form will be submitted by any submit button by default. You either need to create one form per line for simple HTML functionality, or intercept the submission with JS and determine which fields is to be submitted based on which button was clicked.

Comment: I think you are close Stan, but how do I make each row a separate form?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add either a hidden field with an id value that can identify the unique item being passed for updating, and then in your update query you can set WHERE item_id = $item_id.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you are updating every record in your table. To update a selected row you need to pass an unique id which you can do by giving a hidden field in the form. You must pull that unique column say "id" from your table. It must be something like this:

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($siteresult)){

$resultstring .= "<tr>";
$resultstring .= "<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$data['id'].'" />
<input type='text' value='$data[apart_num]' name='apart' name='apart' </td>";
$resultstring .= "<td>$data[address]</td>";
........
}
```

Now accordingly your update script must be like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE your_table SET apart='$apart', address='$address' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

You may add as many as columns here but make sure to use the WHERE clause.